# Large .a file not linking in android

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am facing this issue where i am trying to build a native library for an android app. For that i have a static library (.a), which gets linked into a dynamic library (.so). Now the problem is that the static library is too large (more than 2 GB). And when i compile the dynamic library, it tries to link with the static library and it fails with the below error:

```
d:/adt/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: fatal error: E:\lib\libapplogic.a: pread failed: Invalid argument
```

Has anyone faced this? Resolution?

Comment: That size seems rather absurd, though it may or may not be the immediate cause of the failure.  Are you sure this library is even build for Android?  Isn't there a more sensible way to accomplish your goal - either by turning off unused features during the library build, or by packaging data separately from the code?

Comment: I am sure that the size is not absurd. I DO HAVE that amount of code that compiles into libapplogic.a. I have the option of breaking this into two libraries, is that what you are suggesting? I don't have the option of removing features or disabling pieces of code.

Comment: You have two gigabytes of code you actually use?  Perhaps you forget that you are targeting **a mobile phone**?  Anyway, if you are serious about solving the problem, the first thing to do is to *temporarily* make a drastically cut down or trivially simple substitute, and try linking that.  That will give you some idea of where the problem lies.

Comment: That is a separate discussion :)

Comment: No, it's not.  When you do unreasonable things far outside the bounds of what the system was designed to accommodate, you should expect odd failure modes.

Comment: Ok. The error is thrown by gcc.exe - do you mean to say that gcc.exe or ld.exe is not supposed to build large code?

Comment: Perhaps not, especially these versions and running on windows.  You might well be the first person who has ever tried to cram something so insanely large through them.  Anyway, the test is to see if a reasonably sized substitute works.  If that doesn't, you have a procedural problem.  If it does, you are overloading the capabilities of the system (which is probably going to cause numerous other problems anyway).

Comment: Did you build in debug mode by any chance? We are experiencing the same issue. In debug mode our .a file is 2.2GB while in release its as sleek as 80MB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For others facing this problem: I was able to link the binary using the --no-map-whole-files option.